# 401 status error while using PRAW (reddit)

Tags: python-3.x, reddit, praw

```
import praw
import pandas as pd

reddit = praw.Reddit("bot1")

posts=[]
target_subreddit=reddit.subreddit("Python")
for post in target_subreddit.hot(limit=10):
        posts.append([pos.title, post.score, post.url])
        posts=pd.DataFrame(posts, columns=['title','score','url'])

posts.to_csv('result.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf=8')
```

I have configured the praw.ini file with client_id, client _secret, and user_agent named bot1.
while running this code, I encountered prawcore.exceptions.ResponseException: received 401 HTTP error

can anyone let me know what's the issue?

Comment: http 401 is unauthorized. So your credentials are probably wrong or could not be loaded. Try setting your credentials directly and then put it in an extra file/load it from environment variables: `r = praw.Reddit(client_id=config["client_id"], client_secret=config["client_secret"], password=config["password"],user_agent=config["user_agent"],username=config["username"])`